# Resource Not found getting error while making simple project?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am making simple hello world project in spring using MVC .Hi Found this error resource not found .I take help from this link .
http://crunchify.com/hello-world-example-spring-mvc-3-2-1/

can copy call file .It open the first index.jsp contend But when I click the link it say resource not found .

Here is my error![image]

I copy all code .here is file code .
**web.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>FirstWebProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**crunchify-servlet.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.crunchify.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

controller

```
package com.crunchify.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div align='center'>" + "<h1>Hello World, Spring 3.2.1 Example by Crunchify.com<h1> <br>";
        message += "<a href='http://crunchify.com/category/java-web-development-tutorial/'>More Examples</a>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.2.1 MVC Series: Index - Crunchify.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div align='center'>
    <h2>

            Your 1st Spring MCV Example <br> <br>
            <a href="welcome.jsp">Click here to See Welcome Message...</a>

        </h2>
            <br> by <a href="http://crunchify.com">Crunchify.com</a>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.2.1 MVC Example: Hello World - Crunchify.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is checking for "welcome.html" instead of "welcome.jsp"

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.2.1 MVC Series: Index - Crunchify.com</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <div align='center'>
  <h2>

        Your 1st Spring MCV Example <br> <br>
        <a href="welcome.jsp">Click here to See Welcome Message...</a>

  </h2>
  <br> by <a href="http://crunchify.com">Crunchify.com</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever you use to create a web application, make an entry for welcome file list in your web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Have u changed the href value in index.jsp from welcome.html to welcome.jsp ?

Comment: And move that index.jsp to the jsp folder where welcome.jsp exists

Comment: Please check my update question still I am getting same issue

Comment: can you please give one hello word project using MVC

Comment: I think u have not added any jar files in your library. Add the following jars in your lib folder,                             common-logging-x.x.jar
jstl-x.x.jar
spring-aspects-x.x.jar
spring-beans-x.x.jar
spring-context-x.x.jar
spring-core-x.x.jar
spring-expression-x.x.jar
spring-webmvc-x.x.jar

Answer (score 0):

follow given tutorial carefully and make following changes

***web.xml***

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

read about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039330)

***index.jsp***

```
<a href="welcome.html">Click here to See Welcome Message...</a>
```

when you click on this link new GET request will be generated and redirected to mapped controller

***Controller***

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String message = "<br><div align='center'>" + "<h1>Hello World, Spring 3.2.1 Example by Crunchify.com<h1> <br>";
        message += "<a href='http://crunchify.com/category/java-web-development-tutorial/'>More Examples</a>";
    //add message into module
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
        //name of jsp to show        
    return "welcome";
    }
}
```

then your helloWorld() method will get called which will add your message into ModelMap and send request to welcome.jsp file.

hope this will help you!